# How to expose a property from an QML ComboBox component?

Tags: qt, qml

I am making a ComboBox based component.

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

ComboBox {
   id: _ComboBox
   property alias textInBox: _delegateText.text

   delegate: ItemDelegate {
        contentItem: Text {
        id: _delegateText
        text: name
        }
   }
}
```

When I add a line:
`property alias textInBox: _delegateText.text`, I get the termination of program without starting it yet.

[image]

Tell me how to set the text property from the outside?

Comment: You can use https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-combobox.html#currentText-prop or https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-combobox.html#editText-prop to get the text of the current item. If you don't want the text of the current item, it would be worthwhile explaining what your goal is so that we can help you find a better approach.

Comment: By the way, I can't reproduce that crash on Windows using Qt 5.9.9, 5.13.2, or 6.0 (with both qmlscene and a Qt Quick application). It's probably something in your main.cpp that's making it crash.

Comment: @Mitch I looked in the application output and there is an error. Error: qrc:/modules/ExComboBox.qml:6:31: Invalid alias reference. Unable to find id "_delegateText"

Comment: @Mitch I don't want to get the value, but I want to set the value.

Comment: You shouldn't access a delegate item from outside. It's kind of lazy loading and such item isn't visible from outside. Even more, it is absolutely wrong way - to work with declarative language in a imperative way. You should either work with models, and update a model data provider instead to change a value. If you can tell us your _real purpose_ we can provide an appropriate solution.

Comment: @folibis I want to make a versatile Combobox. In another variant, there may be a model without the `name` field, but with the `description` field. I just want to write the `description` field from the outside and for ComboBox to display it.

Comment: @folibis I want to transfer to the ComboBox the model and the name of the field from the model that needs to be displayed in the ComboBox.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution. Depending on the transferred role in the ComboBox, the corresponding field from the model will be displayed.

ExComboBox.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

ComboBox {
   delegate: ItemDelegate {
      contentItem: Text {
         text: model[textRole]
      }
   }
}
```

You need to specify `textRole: "name"` or any other field from the model instead of `"name"`.

main.qml

```
ExComboBox {
   currentIndex: 0
   model: GroupModel { }
   textRole: "name"
}
```

**NOTE:** The `GroupModel` is the model that I get from C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

Property `contentItem` is a `Component` so whatever you put there it's like it was defined in a separate file.

> Defining a Component is similar to defining a QML document. A QML
> document has a single top-level item that defines the behavior and
> properties of that component, and cannot define properties or behavior
> outside of that top-level item. In the same way, a Component
> definition contains a single top level item (which in the above
> example is a Rectangle) and cannot define any data outside of this
> item, with the exception of an id (which in the above example is
> redSquare).

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html

Delegate gets the text from `model`, so you should work on your model rather than a delegate instances. In your delegate you usually access text through `modelData` property, but it can be customized.

> Models that do not have named roles (such as the ListModel shown
> below) will have the data provided via the modelData role. The
> modelData role is also provided for models that have only one role. In
> this case the modelData role contains the same data as the named role.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html#models

Thus this is how you assign the text to your delegate.

```
 delegate: ItemDelegate {
       contentItem: Text {
          text: modelData
       }
 }
```

If you want to modify it, you simply modify your `model` and you can create all sorts of bindings. For example this will work (though not recommended):

```
   model: [timer.ctr, timer.ctr * 2]

   Timer {
       id: timer
       repeat: true
       interval: 1000
       running: true

       property int ctr: 0

       onTriggered: ctr++
   }
```